# Maven Nexus V3 wont work with artifactory as a remote repo. How can I get around this issue?

Tags: maven, artifactory, nexus, artifacts, repo

So I currently am trying to get artifacts from repo.osegeo.org, which is a Nexus V3. I am having issues getting the artifacts to populate into my virtual repo that i created which holds the remote osegeo repo, libs release, libs snapshot and also my local repos. I have tried following the work around that is stated in this link below:

https://community.sonatype.com/t/maven-nexus-v3-remote-repository-integration-with-artifactory/2149

But I still have trouble actually getting the artifacts in my repo. Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Hi -- i'm having a similar issue now.  Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking the following:

1. Connectivity - Is Artifactory able to reach the Nexus repository and vice versa?
2. The URL which is configured and if it is configured correctly.
3. Enable Bypass HEAD requests on the remote repository - Nexus can block HEAD requests and by default, Artifactory will create HEAD requests first before the GET requests to check if the artifact exists before attempting to resolve it.
4. If the Nexus repository requires authentication - Do not forget to put username and password under the advanced tab.
5. If there is also a reverse proxy in front of Nexus, you can try to bypass it and check if this works, if it does, the problem is probably the RP.
6. Check if the Maven client is configured correctly to work against the virtual repository (You didn't mention if you are able to publish or fetch from the local repository).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I can confirm that i am able to fetch and publish to the local repo